# rfkill unblock all service does not work on ArchLinux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, arch-linux, systemctl

I'm trying to set up my HP EliteBook 2530p with ArchLinux. Everything works except for the wifi card which is hardblocked by default.

Typing `rfkill unblock all` works and unblocks the wifi card until I restart the computer.

I'd like to set up systemctl to start the rfkill unblock service when my computer starts, but `systemctl enable rfkill-unblock@all.service` doesn't work. The service symbolic link is created, but when I reboot the computer and log in I still need to unblock my card manually. The funny part is that `systemctl start rfkill-unblock@all.service` works.

I think that something re-blocks my card after it has been unblocked, but I can't figure out what...

I tried to follow these instructions https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1210751#p1210751 but it doesn't work for me...

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the output of `systemctl status rfkill-unblock@all.service`?

Comment: @bennofs Okay:

`rfkill-unblock@all.service - RFKill-Unblock all`  
`Loaded: loaded /usr/lib/systemd/system/rfkill-unblock@.service; enabled)`  
`Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2013-09-01 00:19:17 CEST; 14s ago`  
`Process: 179 ExecStart=/usr/bin/rfkill unblock %I (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

Answer (score 0):

I also had a HP EliteBook 2530p with the same issue and solved it. To get my WiFi Card unblocked automatically I first followed the instructions from the link shared by Luda.

So first, create the file `rfkill-unblock.service`

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/rfkill-unblock.service
```

and inserted the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=RFKill-Unblock All Devices

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rfkill unblock all
ExecStop=
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Afterwards I enabled and started the startup-Script

```
systemctl enable rfkill-unblock.service
systemctl start rfkill-unblock.service
```

In a second step, I edited the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` accordingly.

```
nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

network={
        ssid="Name of AP"
        proto=WPA
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=TKIP
        group=TKIP
        psk="Passphrase"
}
```

Finally I followed the [archWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_setup) and added the second unit, to bring the interface up and connect it to the AP on startup. Therefore, I created a file called `wifi@[interface].service`. [interface] must be replaced by the name (e.g. `wlan0`, `wls1`, etc.). The name can be retrieved with `iw dev`.

In my case I used the following commands:

```
iw dev
nano /etc/systemd/system/wifi@wls1.service
```

and put this text into the file.

```
[Unit]
Description=
#Wants=network.target
#Before=network.target
Wants=rfkill-unblock.service
After=rfkill-unblock.service
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/ip link set dev %i up
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wpa_supplicant -B -i %i -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dhcpcd %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/ip link set dev %i down

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I changed the the dependency of this service, so it is not started with the network but after the rfkill-unblock.service. Once again I enabled and started the script.

```
systemctl enable wifi@wls1.service
systemctl start wifi@wls1.service
```

In my case, my wifi-device seems to connect on startup.

I hope this is of any help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure `urfkill`. This seems to work for me on Ubuntu:

```
# cat /etc/urfkill/urfkill.conf |grep '^[[:alpha:]]\|\['
[general]
user=root
master_key=true
force_sync=true
persist=true
```